# Google Docs Forms - need Pre-fill Date & Time Entry with current date and current time

Tags: google-forms

Google Forms I need Pre-filled current Date & current Time Entry in date and time fields of my google form. How to do it

Comment: You will need to get the prefilled url either manually or with code, and then use the url to open the Form.  You can send respondents a form with some fields already filled in.

1) Open a form in Google Forms. 2) In the top right, click More . 3) Choose Get pre-filled link. 4) Fill in any answer fields you want to pre-populate. 5) Click Submit.  To send the pre-populated form to respondents, copy and send the link at the top.

Comment: @SandyGood. Thanks for replying. In  step 4 i want that the date and time should be pre-populated with current time and date when respondents are submitting it. The problem is If at time of generating pre filled url I give some values to these fields for e.g. date- 01/01/1990 and time 01:34 PM then to all respondents using prefilled url will get this date and time in the fields which i dont want. I want there local current date and time.     I know in spredsheet attached to form have timestamp but for some reason I want it through fform as well.

Comment: The user would need to run an Apps Script program to get the current date and time, then build the prefilled URL, and then display the prefilled URL to the user.  You could do that with an Apps Script Web App.  You would need to create a Web App with a stand alone apps script file, that has a user interface created with HTML, CSS and JavaScript.  The Web App could be nothing more than a title and a button.  The button would run a script, and create the prefilled URL, then display a link to the user.  Then the user would need to click the link.  This way everyone always has the same link.

Comment: Here is a link to an Apps Script file that is an example of the basic parts of a Web App:  [Link to my shared Apps Script file](https://script.google.com/d/1Pks8u_9N95UkvkoCejLtryrsNsVGTjGgjS3U0opAl-X0f0k5O3JrIQ78/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: @SandyGood Thanks for sharing it. I will need to learn app script part and will try the solution. Really appreciate your time.

Answer (score 3):

My solution is to make the Date field optional. The default is to assume the todays date which is what you get from the timestamp field. In case it needs to be anything else you can enter it manually.

Comment: Unfortunately it seems that an optional date field no longer defaults to the current date.

Answer (score 2):

A simple code-free solution is to make separate sections in your form and use the feature that routes users to different sections based on responses.  The first section asks whether the form is for the current date/time.  If yes, you use the timestamp as the date and time and route the user to the main section with your questions.  If not, route them to a section to set the date and time, and then after that route them to the main section.

Comment: See @Matt Browne above - Is this really true? "an optional date field no longer defaults to the current date"? How about a required date field?

Answer (score 0):

**2023 Solution**
-*Google Forms has updated how dates are passed through URL parameters.*

Instead of passing each component of a date as a separate param, you now pass them using the same syntax as all other fields using the `YYYY-MM-DD` format for your date value.

Here is an example URL:

```
`https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/${formId}/viewform?usp=pp_url&entry.${dateEntryFieldID}=${YEAR}-${MONTH}-${DAY}`
```